# data is not shown in data grid view

Tags: c#, .net

Data is not showing in data grid view

```
    objWorOrder = new WorkOrderBAL();
    objProperties = new OMSProperties();
    objProperties.SO = txtsono.Text;
    DataTable dt = objWorOrder.GetDetail(objProperties);// this is for sql database stored procedure
    dgvActSG.DataSource = dt;
    dgvActSG.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    int rcount = dt.Rows.Count;

    if (dgvActSG.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        var row = dgvActSG.Rows[0];

        txtcustomer.Text = row.Cells[2].Value.ToString();

        dgvActSG.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0]; //set focus to first cell in first row
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Number", "Error");
    }
```

Comment: `dgvActSG.AutoGenerateColumns = false;` occurs after you assign the DataSource so it does not have an impact.  There appears to be something else going on other than what you have showed us here.  Is the Message box being displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you forgot to bind your gridview

```
 dgvActSG.DataSource = dt;
dgvActSG.DataBind();
    dgvActSG.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    int rcount = dt.Rows.Count;
```

Comment: DataBinding is automatic outside ASP.NET.  Explicit calls are unnecessary.